# Recreate an array with the same index to be multidimentional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array as an output which stores different values at the same index

```
Array ( [0] => 79 ) Array ( [0] => 56 ) Array ( [0] => 3 )
```

how can i make it look like this

```
Array[0] ( [0] => 79 , [1] => 56 , [2] => 3 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
$array = array(array(79), array(56), array(3));
```

This works:

```
$array = array_map('current', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

You would use as such:

```
$ret = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

Numeric keys get renumbered.